# C++ basic type demotion when returning from a function

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, type-conversion

I'm getting a (expected)

> warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [`-Woverflow`]

on `Get2()` but on not on `Get1()`. I'm quite puzzled why:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t Get1()
{
      return uint8_t(uint64_t(10000));
}

uint8_t Get2()
{
     return uint64_t(10000);
}

int main()
{
     return 0;
}
```

This is a simplified version of some templated code doing other things - without hard-coded values.
The same happens in C++ when compiled either with GCC or Clang.

Comment: it is `uint64_t(10000)` or `(uint64_t)10000`?

Comment: The key word here is *implicitly*. Your first snippet *explictly* truncates 64 bits into 8, so the compiler assumes you know what you're doing. The second snippet does that *implicitly*, so the compiler warns you just in case you're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The complaint is that there **is** a warning on `Get1`, but **not** on `Get2`, the reverse of what you are suggesting.

Comment: The warning is reported for `Get2`, not for `Get1`.

Comment: @dlask Oh, so the question is asking the exact reverse of what it meant to? Helpful.

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, exactly! :-)

Comment: Fixed the question. All the compilers I tried warn on `Get2()`, but not `Get1()`... which makes way more sense than the alterantive...

Comment: @Barry thanks for fixing it, I was quite confused myself as to why it was `Get1()` and not `Get2()`

Comment: @Barry Sorry, you' re right. On my initial (not published) text I had something like "not getting a warning..." but changed the sentence and forgot to swap Get1() by Get2() ... cheers

Comment: That is no valid C code. Please remove the C tag

Comment: @Olaf would you care to explain why?

Comment: `return uint64_t(10000)` is not valid C. You atually should know that if you tag code as `C`. Try to compile using a proper C compiler. C and C++ are **different languages**! C also has does not support _templates_. For other differences: just read a book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning, which [is reported on the `Get2` function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/585665596042de6c), is there because there's an *implicit* conversion (as opposed to the explicit one you have on `Get1`) happening, and the compiler is warning you that the integer is being truncated.

The explicit one is not being reported, because you have explicitly told the compiler that you are performing a truncation, so a warning would probably be redundant in that case.

Comment: Nice answer. I just linked my answer to yours for reference :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30939274/2173917) by Mr [Jefffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493122/jefffrey),

from the `return` statement Semantics, `C11`, chapter `§6.8.6.4`

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression. **If the expression has a type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.**

In case of `Get1()`, because of the explicit cast, the final expression type is `uint8_t` which matches the return type of the function.

In case of `Get2()`, the final expression type is `uint64_t` which does not matches the return type `uint8_t` of the function.

So, in case of `Get2()`, the type is getting *converted* (as if by assignment) and due to the mismtach in type, the warning is produced.